# Logrotate not deleting rotated logs

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd, logrotate, log-rotation

I've implemented a Fluentd sidecar to rotate logfiles stored on a Kubernetes cluster.

The container uses the following config to run logrotate every 15 minutes on a cronjob.

```
*/15 * * * *    /usr/sbin/logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.conf
```

/etc/logrotate.conf below

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log
{
  size 10M
  missingok
  notifempty
  copytruncate
  rotate 5
  su root root
}
```

This appears to be succesfully rotating logfiles when they reach roughly 10M, however logfiles are not being purged once the **.5** logfile is rolled. It's possible some are, but some are reaching **.9**. Filesystem below:

```
     0 Apr 20 21:48 ./6270fe6c6875e47272ce4d5c4cbd5766ce934c79878f50166211803f78e862cb/6270fe6c6875e47272ce4d5c4cbd5766ce934c79878f50166211803f78e862cb-json.log
   569 Apr 20 21:48 ./6270fe6c6875e47272ce4d5c4cbd5766ce934c79878f50166211803f78e862cb/6270fe6c6875e47272ce4d5c4cbd5766ce934c79878f50166211803f78e862cb-json.log.1
  9.5M Apr 20 22:00 ./e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de/e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de-json.log.9
  9.5M Apr 20 22:00 ./e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de/e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de-json.log.8
  9.5M Apr 20 22:00 ./e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de/e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de-json.log.7
  9.5M Apr 20 22:00 ./e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de/e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de-json.log.6
  9.5M Apr 20 22:00 ./e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de/e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de-json.log.5
  9.5M Apr 20 22:00 ./e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de/e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de-json.log.4
  9.5M Apr 20 22:00 ./e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de/e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de-json.log.3
  9.5M Apr 20 22:00 ./e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de/e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de-json.log.2
  9.5M Apr 20 22:00 ./e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de/e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de-json.log.1
787.1K Apr 20 22:08 ./e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de/e21792c56001e343291e64927dcfc8dd5be3449b0c347c41211aa450ba0ce7de-json.log
     0 Apr 20 21:48 ./bbec8c11ef419591efdbe6850144cac5bfb77222e8024447f9b15422d3e2b0ca/bbec8c11ef419591efdbe6850144cac5bfb77222e8024447f9b15422d3e2b0ca-json.log
146.4K Apr 20 21:48 ./bbec8c11ef419591efdbe6850144cac5bfb77222e8024447f9b15422d3e2b0ca/bbec8c11ef419591efdbe6850144cac5bfb77222e8024447f9b15422d3e2b0ca-json.log.1
  8.0M Apr 20 22:08 ./33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log
  7.0M Apr 20 21:58 ./33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.5
  7.1M Apr 20 21:59 ./33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.4
  7.1M Apr 20 22:00 ./33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.3
  7.1M Apr 20 22:00 ./33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.2
  7.2M Apr 20 22:00 ./33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.1
     0 Apr 20 10:46 ./f683a00adabfc6ea9b4edfd19c336d3bd2e0e5747fb8b49713ffb5e002f4266e/f683a00adabfc6ea9b4edfd19c336d3bd2e0e5747fb8b49713ffb5e002f4266e-json.log
```

I don't know if perhaps I'm using an invalid configuration? I don't need to keep the logs for long, they're shipped to AWS CloudWatch almost as quickly as they're written - I just need the nodes to not consume disk space.

Log output (trimmed)...

```
reading config file /etc/logrotate.conf
Reading state from file: /var/lib/logrotate.status
Allocating hash table for state file, size 64 entries
Creating new state
...
Creating new state

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log
 7340032 bytes (5 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/lib/docker/containers/052e7eaaab7bfe74e77a2e43f314a0dd219ddfd998ad670cab4936fa2ee16937/052e7eaaab7bfe74e77a2e43f314a0dd219ddfd998ad670cab4936fa2ee16937-json.log
  Now: 2021-04-21 10:45
  Last rotated at 2021-04-21 08:45
  log does not need rotating (log size is below the 'size' threshold)
...
...
rotating log /var/lib/docker/containers/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log, log->rotateCount is 5
dateext suffix '-20210421'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/lib/docker/containers/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.5 to /var/lib/docker/containers/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.6 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 5),
renaming /var/lib/docker/containers/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.4 to /var/lib/docker/containers/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.5 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 4),
renaming /var/lib/docker/containers/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.3 to /var/lib/docker/containers/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.4 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 3),
renaming /var/lib/docker/containers/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.2 to /var/lib/docker/containers/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.3 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 2),
renaming /var/lib/docker/containers/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.1 to /var/lib/docker/containers/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.2 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 1),
renaming /var/lib/docker/containers/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.0 to /var/lib/docker/containers/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.1 (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 0),
old log /var/lib/docker/containers/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.0 does not exist
copying /var/lib/docker/containers/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log to /var/lib/docker/containers/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.1
truncating /var/lib/docker/containers/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log
removing old log /var/lib/docker/containers/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e/33f2d4ad5090b8699ace2942e398b64707074b2aed28000887214f4594ce165e-json.log.6
```

Comment: Hello @Garreth. Could you please add logrotate output to your question? You can get it by running `/usr/sbin/logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.conf` manually.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor please see revised answer. Thanks